# How does `Alt` decide which strings is a word in bash?

Tags: bash

I can use `Alt+f`, `Alt+b` and a series of other `Alt` command to doing things with `word`. But the concept `word` is vague for me.

From my experience, `.` `,` `_` are valid separator for word, meanwhile `'` not,
but is there a clear doc which tells us which separator are valid for `word` in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash (among other command line applications) uses a library called Readline for allowing the user to enter commands. The shortcuts you mentioned are Readline shortcuts (specifically, Readline in Emacs mode). You can check out the documentation for Readline [here](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html).

The answer to your specific question is that words are ["composed of letters and digits"](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC5).

Comment: I used 1@2#3$4%5^6&7*8(9)0-1_2+3=4}5{6[7]8\9|0;1:2'3"4,5<6.7>8/9? to check your definition, so far on digit it's right.

Comment: And seems if you have a string named ^!@#$%^&abc the Readline stuff will recognize ^!@ as the beginning of the string, so things comes crystal clean now! Thanks.